# Actualizar registro base de datos CakePHP

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

He hecho un formulario para modificar los datos de un registro concreto de mi tabla "datospagos", pero recibo el siguiente error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Parece que se debe a que no esta actualizando directamente el registro, sino que esta intentando crear uno nuevo, y cuando ve que ya existe uno con la misma primary key lanza el error, entonces lo que quiero es que en vez de crearlo lo actualice. Este es el formulario:

```
<div class="panel panel-warning row">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h4>Edición Datos Pagos Reparadora</h4></div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 2em;">
        <?php echo $this->Form->create('Datospago'); ?>
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('FK_PROPIETARIO'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('PK_DATOSPAGO')?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('MERCHANT_ID', array(
                    'label' => '<h4><strong>Merchant ID:</strong></h4>',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'div' => array('class' => 'col-md-6'),
                    'required' => true,
                    'maxlength' => 100
                )
            );
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('MERCHANT_KEY', array(
                    'label' => '<h4><strong>Merchant Key:</strong></h4>',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'div' => array('class' => 'col-md-6'),
                    'required' => true,
                    'maxlength' => 100
                )
            );
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(array('label' => 'Actualizar Datos de Pago', 'class' => 'btn btn-warning')); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y esta es la accion mediante la cual actualizo el registro de la base de datos con $this->Datospago->save($this->request->data), que segun he leido en la documentacion sirve para actualizar datos de una tabla.

```
public function edit($id = null)
    {
        if(!$id)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }

        $datospago = $this->Datospago->findByPkDatospago($id);
        if(!$datospago)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }

        if($this->request->is(array('post', 'put')))
        {
            $this->Datospago->PK_DATOSPAGO = $id;

            if($this->Datospago->save($this->request->data))
            {
                $this->Flash->success('Los datos de pago han sido modificados');
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'edit', $id));
            }
            $this->Flash->warning('El registro no pudo ser modificado.');
        }

        if(!$this->request->data)
        {
            $this->request->data = $datospago;
        }
    }
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro: *`Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`* significa que existe ya un valor `1` para la llave primaria de la tabla, por tanto, no puedes ni insertar ni actualizar un registro asignándole el valor `1` en la llave primaria, porque ese valor ya existe. Convendría escribir una función que verifique que no hay duplicados antes de insertar/actualizar los registros.

Comment: Entonces debería comprobar primero si existe, y en caso de que si exista ya, eliminarlo y crear uno nuevo con los datos introducidos? No hay alguna manera de que se actualicen? En este caso siempre va a existir un registro cada vez que se use el formulario por lo que siempre se va a actualizar un registro y no crear uno nuevo, por eso, no existe en Cakephp alguna forma de actualizar un registro sin tener que eliminarlo y crearlo de nuevo con los mismos datos?